# Run script in newly opened tab

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing a chrome extension which will open new tab. My question is how can I get the newly opened tab? When I reach that new tab, I want to make some changes in the source code.
This; https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-create creates new tab. But I want to make some changes before user click the tab. (Change the selected value and run inside function)

How can I do this with method create?

Answer (score 2):

There is a callback parameter for [`chrome.tabs.create`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-create), you could call [`chrome.tabs.executeScript`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript) inside it and inject some code into the created tab.

```
chrome.tabs.create({url: 'http://www.google.com'}, function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {code: 'document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'green;'});
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I should enhance my question. In my extension popup, I have 3 different tabs to go. So how can I run the script when the url is what I want.

Comment: used matches in content_script (manifest) https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#registration

Comment: @user6468132, do you mean you created three tabs while only want the scripts to be run in specific url? So you could determine whether to inject the scripts by checking `tab.url` or just make the restrictions in `manifest.json` for `matches` field, it can restrict which url your script can be injected in